# How to make the different "mat-option" independent of each other

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngfor, angular-components, angular-ng-if

**I'm currently facing a problem with a Angular Component : Mat-option. I would like to make each of my mat-option independent from the other.**

Im actually using a component Template which is called each time I use a button "Ajouter Habilitations". When I click on it, a new component is created and with an API, fullfill the different mat option. There is firstly only one list called "Environnement", then with a ngIf, the second will appear depending on the environement selected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNL67.png)

There is firstly only one list called "Environnement", then with a ngIf, the second will appear depending on the environment selected

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBi7P.png)

My first list is filled with different environment. and the second, depending on the environment specificities, is using one of the two table here :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b1WY.png)

The problem here, is that each time I'm creating a new component, the different mat-option seem to be linked. Here an example of what happened when I select an environment, then I choose an other without the same spec.

Environment without specifics : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JURTa.png)
Different environment without specifics : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42SMa.png)

What happened when one environment with specifics is selected : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWYev.png)

So basically, when I select a specific environment, the mat-option are drained, and the option of their list is now the same as the specific one.

**Here my request** : I would like to make independent mat-option with a list completed depending only about the environment on the same line.

```
                                                                             There is my code :
```

```
<div id='{{i}}' *ngIf="appliL5X_Choisie">
    <div>{{i}}</div>
    <mat-form-field id='{{i}}'>
      <mat-select formControlName="environnement" class="no-hover" placeholder="Environnement">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let env of envListeSpec.env" [value]="env" (click)="envChoisi(env,i)">  {{env}}
          </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="envChoisiSansSpec">
      <mat-select formControlName="droit" multiple class="no-hover" placeholder="Type de droits">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let droit of listeDroitClassique" [value]="droit.name">
            {{droit.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="envChoisiAvecSpec">
          <mat-select formControlName="droit" multiple class="no-hover" placeholder="Type de droits">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let droit of listeDroitSpec" [value]="droit.name">
                {{droit.name}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="remove(habilitation, i)">Supprimer</button>
</div>
```

---------------------------------------------------

I've tried to use the index of each component from different ways, using css or native function of the component like OnInit. But it has never worked.

Comment: i think you need to share code logic behind selection of env (first selection) change so depend on it second one is filter

Comment: You're right. Each Environment is specific or not. So when i retrieve data with my API, I recover the name of the environment and a number, 0 or 1. If it's 0, it's not specific. Otherwise it is.

Comment: as per env selection you have perform any filter for second list?

Comment: Yes. As you can see, there is a ngIf on the two last mat-form-field. The ngIf is based on a boolean value. Either "envChoisiSansSpec" which is true if the environment selected is not specific, or "envChoisiAvecSpec" which is true in the contrary case. 

Depending on those variables, the second list mit mat-option will choose between two table as I showed in my post. Those table, "listeDroitClassique" if environment is not specific, and "listeDroitSpec" if it is.

Comment: understood can you able to provide code snipt